# Need help to loop curl function over links

Tags: php, loops, curl, foreach

Hi i'm having a hard time to loop my curl function and automate the job .

$scrape_url is a function to grab link from a page .
  scrape_nextpage is a function that grab the url of the  "next" page where i will use   $scrape_url again , and so on 
here is so far my code :

```
$url = "http://website.com";   

$results_page = scrape_url($url); 

 if ( $url !==scrape_nextpage($url) ) {

        $url = scrape_nextpage($url);

       $results_page = scrape_url($url);
```

and i want to loop through each $url i found in the page (kind of going through the pagination)

so far i only get the 2 first pages , and i need to fetch the other pages

Update :
scrape_nextpage()  is a curl function that grab the url of the next page ( example :

scrape_nextpage() grab the url : "website.com/next30post.html";

so the new $url to use in  scrape_url($url) become  "website.com/next30post.html" .

then  i fetch the same page  with scrape_nextpage() to get "website.com/next60post.html"; and so on .

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
$url = "http://website.com";  
$results_page = scrape_url($url);  

while ($url !== scrape_nextpage($url))
{
    $url = get_nextpage($url);
    if (!$url) {
        break;
    }
    $results_page = scrape_url($url);
    // do something with $results_page
}
```

Just make sure `get_nextpage()` returns `FALSE` or an empty string when there's no more urls to check - that will break the while loop.

**Update:**

Your function naming is very vague. It's totally unclear what they do. You want clear names.

As an example, you want a function `get_content($url);` that takes url of some page (for example, `http://website.com`) and returns HTML of that web page. Second function you need is a function `grab_links($html);` that will parse HTML of some page and return you the links it found there. Then the code will be:

```
$list_of_urls = array(
    "http://website.com"
    );
foreach ($list_of_urls as $url)
{
    $html = get_content($url);
    $links = grab_links($html);
    // do something with $links
}
```

Now this is clear and can be easily debugged.

Comment: i ryed similar but without any success ! the thing is that i want to loop the "scrape url" over each "scrape next" page i found  .

Comment: @user2158439 please update the answer with exact description of what functions `scrape_nextpage()` and `get_nextpage()` do.

Comment: scrape_nextpage() and get_nextpage() is the same curl function that grab the url of the next page ( example :  scrape_nextpage() grab the url of "http://website.com/next30post.html" where i would be using scrape_url($url) and then fetch in that page again using scrape_nextpage() to get "http://website.com/next60post.html" and so on .

Comment: Look into the update of the answer. You want to store list of urls you grab clearly, like in a var `$list_of_urls` and you also want to rename your functions.

Comment: thanks for your answers ! the thing is for : $list_of_urls = array(
    "http://website.com"
    );  im using   scrape_nextpage($url) to get the $url to fetch , so i don't have them yet i only start with 1 and i check if it's not similar so i use the url found on the scrape_nextpage($url) function

Comment: Your function needs improvement. It should take `$url` and return next url or `FALSE` if there's no more urls. The check if it's similar should be within the function. Then you can use `while ($url = scrape_nextpage($url)) {}`